# Changing Default port for Nagios NSClient++

Tags: nagios, nsclient++

The default port for NSClient++ is 12489. Is is possible to change this port, and if so where does this change need to be made?

Answer (score 2):

The TCP port 12489 is the default port for using check_nt not for all the services offered by nsclient.

If you want to change the default port, you can do this in the file `nsclient.ini`.

You would have something like this :

```
<snip>
[/settings/NSClient/server]

; ENABLE SSL ENCRYPTION - This option controls if SSL should be enabled.
use ssl = 0

; PERFORMANCE DATA - Send performance data back to Nagios (set this to 0 to remove all performance data).
performance data = 1

; PORT NUMBER - Port to use for check_nt.
port = 12489 <= CHANGE HERE TO HAVE YOUR NEW LISTENING PORT
<snip>
```

After, don't forget to restart your service. And test with `netstat` to be sure your new port is correctly opened.